# Open spreadsheet fails in Time Book Application tutorial

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

This is based on the "Time Booking Application" tutorial.
I have created the site and the spreadsheet and the script in the site.
The site page I created fails to open the spreedsheet.

From the script editor in the site I can run the test methods testGetSheet(), testUpdateSheet() and testInsertTimeSheet(). I believe this indicates the SPREADSHEET_ID is correct. However the site page I created for this errors with "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist."

I have tried to share the spreadsheet to be available to anyone with the link and edit ability.
I have tried to share the spreadsheet to public and edit ability.
I have tried this from a seperate unauthenticated browser and from an authenticated browser.
I still get the error.
I have run out of ideas, has anyone else an idea ?

I can provide the url to the page on site, but I doubt its of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes answering my own question.
After much research and experiments.
The problem is with access to the script the tutorial does not say anything about permissions or anything.

Anyway solution is.  Publish script as Web App use the URL to web app in the App Script Gadget. I have posted this feedback on the tutorial documenation allready.

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing, thank you so much for the answer !!